# JS array of arrays to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multi-select

I have a JS array (shown 4 examples actual has 66 )

```
[["A","Example1"],["A","Example2"],["B","Example3"],["B","Example4"]]
```

that I am trying to get into an object for a multi select drop down menu:

```
var opt = [{
label: 'A', children:[
        {"label":"Example1","value":"Example1","selected":"TRUE"},
        {"label":"Example2","value":"Example2","selected":"TRUE"} 
      ]
},

{
label: 'B', children:[
  {"label":"Example3","value":"Example3","selected":"TRUE"},
  {"label":"Example4","value":"Example4","selected":"TRUE"}
  ]
}
]
```

Is there a easy way to do this ?

Comment: It can be done with a single `.reduce()`, though "easy" is certainly relative, and as a result the answer to your question is a subjective "yes" or "no". Perhaps you could share your attempts or a specific difficulty you're encountering, so that we can help out as opposed to writing the code for for you :)

Comment: (For what it's worth I've removed all references to JSON in your question as well, including the title and tags, as it doesn't seem related.)

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure out a way to use For loops. starting with identifying the unique first value of the embedded arrays then loop through the arrays finding which match the list of unique values.

Comment: I think, instead of Array of objects, ES6 maps would make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:
Using `reduce()` and `filter()` to get expected results.

```js
const result = [['A', 'Example1'], ['A', 'Example2'], ['B', 'Example3'], ['B', 'Example4']].reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const objFromAccumulator = acc.filter((row) => row.label === cur[0]);
  const newChild = {label: cur[1], value: cur[1], selected: 'TRUE'};
  if (objFromAccumulator.length) {
    objFromAccumulator[0].children.push(newChild);
  } else {
    acc.push({label: cur[0], children: [newChild]});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is great but backwards from what I'm trying to achieve. I'm wanting to go from the array of array to the 'label' format.

Comment: @TygerGuzman Isn't the result an array of array to the label format from my answer? `[["A",  "Example1"], ["A", "Example2"], ["B", "Example3"], ["B", "Example4"]]`

Comment: I'm trying to go from `[["A","Example1"],["A","Example2"],["B","Example3"],["B","Example4"]]`  to `[{
label: 'A', children:[
        {"label":"Example1","value":"Example1","selected":"TRUE"},
        {"label":"Example2","value":"Example2","selected":"TRUE"} 
      ]
},

{
label: 'B', children:[
  {"label":"Example3","value":"Example3","selected":"TRUE"},
  {"label":"Example4","value":"Example4","selected":"TRUE"}
  ]
}
]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather efficient and concise take on the problem using an object as a map:

```js
const data = [["A","Example1"],["A","Example2"],["B","Example3"],["B","Example4"]];

const opt = data.reduce((results,[key,val]) => {
  if(!results[0][key]) //first element of results is lookup map of other elements
    results.push(results[0][key] = { label: key, children: [] });
  results[0][key].children.push({ label: val, value: val, selected:"TRUE" });
  return results;
}, [{}]).slice(1); //slice off map as it's no longer needed

console.log(opt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
const raw = [["A","Example1"],["A","Example2"],["B","Example3"],["B","Example4"]];

const seen = new Map();
const processed = raw.reduce((arr, [key, label]) => {
    if (!seen.has(key)) {
        const item = {
            label: key,
            children: []
        };
        seen.set(key, item);
        arr.push(item);
    }
    seen.get(key).children.push({
        label,
        value: label,
        selected: "TRUE"
    })
    return arr;
}, []);
console.log(processed);
```